# How to remove margin gap in area spline chart for highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How can I remove margin gap in area spline and stick to the edges

[image]
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline

Answer (score 2):

Add these line to the `xAxis` :

```
xAxis:{
    ...
    min:0.5,
    max:5.5,
    tickInterval:1,
    maxPadding:0,
    endOnTick:false,
    startOnTick:false
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afnd75ty/)

Comment: why 0.5 and 5.5?